# Accessing development folder as if it is node global folder

Tags: node.js, require, node-modules, virtual-path

I've modules folder which contains my modules for app1 and have another module folder for app2 and so on.
I wish to import my modules without passing virtual module paths.

For eg.

```
c:\Projects\Apps\
    firstApp
      www.js // I wish to import db with require('db')
    Modules
      db
         src/...*.js  // var ext=require('extensions')
         test/...*.js
         index.js
      api
         src/
           *.js  // var ext=require('db'),
                 // var ext=require('extensions'),
         test/
           *.js  // var testApi = require('api')
         index.js
      extensions
         src/...*.js
         test/...*.js
         index.js
```

Is there any possibilities to use them as if they are installed localy but in different folders.  `npm link` is usable for this?

Comment: this can be achieved in multiple ways, would you like to set more constraints in your question? for example you could require by giving the path like: `require('../app1/api/src/db')`

Answer (score 0):

`require('...')` will look for modules inside node_modules folder or local files when using `./` or `../`.

What you can do is create your own require function that will look for local files even when not using relative/absolute file paths.

In your root/entry code, use this:

```
var projectDirectory = __dirname;
GLOBAL.requirep = function(path) {
  return require(projectDirectory + '/' + path);
}

//at any js file, you can do this:
var db = requirep('db') //will load db/index.js
var api = requirep('api/src/file.js') //will load api/src/file.js
```

Because it is global, you can access it from wherever you need.